# No TeX support in chat

Tags: support, mathjax, chat

Today the StackExchange system advised me to move one of the comment exchanges to chat. I wanted to do that, but then saw that TeX is not supported and it was almost impossible to follow the train of argument. On the other hand, I fear offending the community for not following the code of conduct. What should I do?

Comment: Check out chatjax: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/should-chat-have-tex-support?rq=1

Comment: Oh--and sometimes the system tells you to move a discussion too early or when it is not practical.  It is an automated alert, too, so you have to use your own judgement sometimes... :)

Comment: Amazing stuff! Someone had commented about the use of Ctrl+Shift+B -- this saved my life! :)